# Showing that $2x^2\cos(1/x) - x + 2$ is strictly increasing on certain intervals

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inequality

**Problem**

Show that the function $2x^2\cos(\frac1x) - x + 2$ is strictly increasing in all intervals of the form $\displaystyle \left[\frac{2}{(4n+1)\pi}, \quad \frac{6}{(12n+1)\pi}\right]$ where $n\in\mathbb N$

**Thoughts**

The derivative I've found to be $f'(x) = 2\sin(\frac1x) + 4x\cos(\frac1x)-1$

At first, I thought of solving $f'(x) > 0$ but that seems more and more preposterous. And besides, I've found that the endpoints of the interval in the problem statement are already increasing, so even though $f$ is supposedly increasing in these intervals, it's not increasing *only* in these intervals. That leads me to believe that the problem is a bit more intricate than I thought.

My second thought was to start with the inequality $\frac{2}{(4n+1)\pi} \leq x \leq \frac{6}{(12n+1)\pi}$ and from there work my way into the result that $f'(x) > 0$, but there too I end up hitting a brick wall because I end up with more inequalities I can't solve.

Comment: To prove $f'(x) > 0$ for $\frac{2}{(4n+1)\pi} \leq x \leq \frac{6}{(12n+1)\pi}$, one may let $x = \frac{1}{2n\pi + y}$ and prove that $f'(x) > 0$ on $y \in [\pi/6, \pi/2]$.

Comment: @RiverLi - That seems promising but I can't quite reach goal. Given the subtitution you propose, I get $$\frac 1x = y + 2n\pi$$ which just simplifies to $y$ when it's an argument of a sin or cos function. So it boils down to $$2\sin y + 4x\cos y > 1$$ which seems close to home. I'm missing the next step though.

Comment: Or rather, I see that if $y \in [\pi/6, \pi/2]$ then the inequality seems to be true, but I can't see how you got that interval.

Comment: You can prove that $2\sin y \ge 1$ on $[\pi/6, \pi/2]$. Then you are done.

Comment: @RiverLi - After some more work, I can now show the truth of the inequality. But I'm only *using* the interval $[\pi/6, \pi/2]$. I don't honestly know how you arrived at that interval in particular.

Comment: From $\left[\frac{2}{(4n+1)\pi}, \quad \frac{6}{(12n+1)\pi}\right]$, the reciprocal of the endpoints are $2n\pi + \pi/2$ and $2n\pi + \pi/6$.